# cant able to close the window when clicked

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qdialog

I cant able to close the window when clicked ok button in PyQt4 application, i tried a lot but nothing worked, iam posting my code below to your reference. 
please do help me...thank you

I cant able to close the window when clicked ok button in PyQt4 application, i tried a lot but nothing worked, iam posting my code below to your reference. 
please do help me...thank you

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'GUIAPP.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 60, 281, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Times New Roman"))
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.label.setIndent(0)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 170, 81, 21))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 170, 81, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.closeEvent)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "ok", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "cancel", None))

    def closeEvent(self):
        self.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Ui_Dialog is not a widget, it is a class that fills the graphic part. You should close the window through `Dialog.close()`, since dialog is a widget. For that you can use the following:

```
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(Dialog.close)
```

complete code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 60, 281, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Times New Roman"))
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.label.setIndent(0)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 170, 81, 21))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 170, 81, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(Dialog.close)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "ok", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "cancel", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another way that is recommended is to implement the class that implements the logic and inherit from QDialog, in addition to using Ui_Dialog as interface.

```
class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(dialog.close)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

complete code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'GUIAPP.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 60, 281, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Times New Roman"))
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.label.setIndent(0)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 170, 81, 21))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 170, 81, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "ok", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "cancel", None))

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(dialog.close)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*Note: closeEvent is a method that runs before a window is closed, analyzes if you need to overwrite it before doing so.*